# What's equal this :$\sum_{\phi(n)=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, totient-function

I'm interesting to know something about convergence of series related to the Euler totient functin, then my question here is  :

> > **Question**
> >
> > Is this a convergent sum  :$\sum_{\phi(n)=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\phi(n)}$ ?

Note: $\phi$ is Euler totient function

Comment: Is the sum over all $n$ where $\phi(n)=1$ or over all possible values of $\phi(n)$?

Comment: The sum over  all possible values of phi(n)

Answer (score 2):

I reckon $\phi(n)\le n$ and so
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{\phi(n)}\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$
etc.

ADDED IN EDIT

I also reckon that if $A=\{\phi(n):n\in\Bbb N\}$ then
$$\sum_{m\in A}\frac1m\ge\sum_p\frac1{\phi(p)}>\sum_p\frac1p$$
where $p$ runs through all primes.

Comment: True, but not what OP is asking for.

Comment: The sum over all possible values of phi(n)

Comment: Well, $\phi(p) = p - 1$ for primes $p$, and the sum of prime reciprocals diverges, so it still diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{\,\phi(n)\mid n\in\Bbb N, n>1\,\}$. If $p$ is prime then in particular $\phi(p)=p-1\in A$. Hence
$$\sum_{a\in A}\frac 1a\ge \sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p-1}\ge \sum_{p\text{ prime}}\frac1{p}=\infty. $$