# What's the closed form of this :$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\phi(n)}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

I have checked some links  related the below sum which is related to The Euler totient function to check if it has any known closed form but i don't find anything then my question here is :

> > **Question:**
> >      What is the closed form of this :$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\phi(n)}{n}$ , where $\phi(n)$ is Euler totient function ?

Comment: That looks pretty divergent to me.

Comment: I would guess, similar answer as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535643/whats-equal-this-sum-phin-1-infty-frac1-phin?rq=1), as Lord Shark just said.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Divergent even with the alternating signs?

Comment: @paw88789 The terms don't converge to $0$. For a prime $p$, we have $\phi(p) = p-1$.

Comment: That's divergent, for prime $n$, it's $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}=1-1/n$, and that doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: $F(s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \phi(2n-1) (2n-1)^{-s} = \frac{(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s-1)}{1-2^{-s} \zeta(s)}$ and $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty  (-1)^n \phi(n) n^{-s} = F(s) (1- \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-sk} \phi(2^k)) = \frac{(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s-1)}{1-2^{-s} \zeta(s)} (1-\frac{2^{-1}}{2^{s-1}-1})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Good point! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated by reuns in the comments, for any $s$ with a large enough real part we have

$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{\varphi(p)}{p^s}+\frac{\varphi(p^2)}{p^{2s}}+\frac{\varphi(p^3)}{p^{3s}}+\ldots\right)= \prod_{p}\frac{p^s-1}{p^s-p}$$
by Euler's product, hence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} = \prod_p \frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}$$
$$ \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\text{ odd}}}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s} = \prod_{p>2} \frac{1-\frac{1}{p^{s}}}{1-\frac{1}{p^{s-1}}}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}\cdot\frac{2^s-2}{2^s-1}$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n \varphi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}\left(1-2\cdot\frac{2^s-2}{2^s-1}\right) =-\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}\cdot\frac{2^s-3}{2^s-1}$$
but the series in the LHS is convergent only for $\text{Re}(s)>2$.