# Evaluating $\mathrm{\sum_{x=2}^\infty \left(\frac1{π^2(x)}+\frac1{π\left(x^2\right)}\right)}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics

It can be [seen](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28-1%29%5En%2Fprimepi%28n%29+from+2+to+10000) that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6},\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{π(n)}=1$$ Where π(x) is the [prime counting function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html) with $π(0\le x<2)$=0 hence the starting index at 2. As there are two examples of convergence, I will add them together for more results. Note that each sum term converges separately. [Sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum++%281%2Fprimepi%28x%29%5E2%2B1%2Fprimepi%28x%5E2%29%29++from+2+to+8000) approximation. You can think of it as the prime pi [basel function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem). I will use many identities from [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/PrimePi/) and [Number Theory functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/NumberTheoryFunctions/). The sums converge slowly:

$$\mathrm{P=\sum_{x=2}^\infty \left(\frac1{π^2(x)}+\frac1{π\left(x^2\right)}\right)=ln\prod_{x=2}^\infty e^{\frac{1}{\pi^2(x)}+\frac{1}{\pi\left(x^2\right)}}=4.71…}$$

$$\mathrm{\sum_{x=2}^\infty \frac1{\pi\big(x^2\big)}=1.86…, \sum_{x=2}^\infty\frac 1{\pi^2(x)}=2.84…}$$

Partial sums for P:

[image]

Summand graph:

[image]

It is possible to get bounds for $x\ge 2$ the summand as both bounds are positive. [Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4cbknkutl3) of bounds:

$$\mathrm{\frac{x}{ln(x)+2}\le\pi(x)\le\frac{x\,ln(4)}{ln(x)}\implies \frac{log_4^2(x)+2log_4(x)}{x^2}\le\pi^{-2}(x)+\frac1{\pi\left(x^2\right)}\le\frac{ln^2(x)+6ln(x)+6}{x^2}}$$

[image]

This gives $2.236…\le \text P\le 6.532…$

I will add more forms. How would one evaluate P? An [exact](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/what-is-exact-form) answer is needed. You can also find an integral representation of P. Please correct me and give me feedback!

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Note that since $2$ is the only even prime number $$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{2N} {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{\pi (n)}}}  = \frac{1}{{\pi (2)}} + \sum\limits_{n = 2}^N {\left[ {\frac{1}{{\pi (2n)}} - \frac{1}{{\pi (2n - 1)}}} \right]}  = \frac{1}{{\pi (2)}} = 1.
$$ Also, $$
\sum\limits_{n = 2}^{2N - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{\pi (n)}}}  = 1 - \frac{1}{{\pi (2N)}}.
$$ This provides a quick proof of your claim based on numerics.

Comment: @Gary Sorry, I put that in just as an example that the sum, in the title, could be evaluated. Perhaps I could use your method to evaluate. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that any of the sums you are considering has a closed form?

Comment: @jjagmath I never said a closed form, an [exact](https://web2.0calc.com/questions/what-is-exact-form) solution is better. Also, [this number theory sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2566910/whats-the-closed-form-of-this-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-phinn?rq=1) has a solution, but it seems true that there is no closed form for this question, so I said an exact answer is better. It is still an interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few manipulation of the series we can prove that

$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi^2(k)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{n^2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty p_n\frac{2n-1}{n^2(n-1)^2}-2$$

This series have a slightly better rate of convergence, but still looks far from a closed form (which I doubt exists).

The series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\pi(k^2)}$ seems much more difficult to handle.

Comment: Thanks, but could you at least try to convert the second sum into another type of series or non-sum form, perhaps $k\to k^2$ would work as a substitution? Also, what identity did you use for the first sum?

Comment: As I said, that looks much more difficult to attack. I have no clue how could be transformed in another series. For the first sum I didn't use any identity, I just rearrange and collect some terms of the series.